# How to LOAD DATA with optional fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, sql-insert, load-data-infile

Is it possible to `LOAD DATA` a `csv` into `mysql` without having to add *empty* values for non existing columns at the end?

All my optional columns are sorted at the end of the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
    id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    optional1 varchar DEFAULT NULL,
    optional... varchar DEFAULT NULL,
    optional50 varchar DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) engine=innodb AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

sample.csv:

```
1;john;doe
2;jabe;doe;;;opt val3;;;;;;opt val9;;;;;;...
```

Important: I don't want to explicit list all the columns in my `LOAD DATA INFILE` sql statement (I know that this would work by using a combination of `IFNULL` and `@var`).

But can't I just load into the table, telling mysql to ignore any missing fields at the end of each line?

Comment: If you're open to taking a different approach to executing your SQL statements, the IMPORT metacommand of execsql.py (https://pypi.org/project/execsql/) will load data with short lines.  Disclaimer: I wrote execsql.  You should set the 'empty_strings' configuration parameter to "No" to force execsql to use its own data loading routine instead of LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [MySQL `LOAD DATA` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) provides the following information:

> By default, when no column list is provided at the end of the `LOAD DATA` statement, input lines are expected to contain a field for each table column. If you want to load only some of a table's columns, specify a column list.
>
> [...]
>
> If an input line has too few fields, the table columns for which input fields are missing are set to their default values. For numeric types, the column is set to `0`.
>
> [...]
>
> An empty field value is interpreted different from a missing field: for string types, the column is set to the empty string.

So given your sample data:

```
1;john;doe
2;jabe;doe;;;opt val3;;;;;;opt val9;;;;;;...
```

Record with id `1` will have all optional columns set to `NULL` (ie their default). For `id`2, optional string columns will be set to the empty string. .

I cannot tell whether this would be OK for your use case or not. If you do want consistent values in the optional columns, available options would be:

- input pre-processing: use `SET` to set to `NULL` columns that contains an empty string

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE t1
    SET 
        optional1 = NULLIF(optional1, ''), 
        optional2 = NULLIF(optional1, ''), 
        ...
```

- set up a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the table that sets to `NULL` empty values
- run an update on the table *after* it was populated

```
    UPDATE t1 SET optional1 = NULLIF(option1, ''), optional2 = NULLIF(optional1, '')
    WHERE '' IN (optional1, optional2, ...)
```

Comment: I know, but I then would have to list all my X optional columns explicit, don't I? I'm looking for a generic solution. I mean, with your example they would *always* be skipped. But I only want to skip those optional columns if not present in the csv line.

Comment: *"If an input line has too few fields, the table columns for which input fields are missing are set to their default values."* if that's true I'd be happy. But when trying to load the sample, I'm getting the `ERROR 1261 (01000): Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it works as expected if adding the `IGNORE` keyword to the `LOAD DATA` statement:

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'sample.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE persons`

Thereby, I can define all my optional columns as `DEFAULT NULL`, and if values are missing, they are set to `NULL` during import.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TRAILING NULLCOLS.

Comment: this is a comment and not the answer